# Multi Threading in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, thread-safety, google-cloud-datastore

How can I make the operations of getting and setting a property from datastore, thread safe?

Currently, I have code which puts tasks in the queue and each task perform a task and then updates a property called of numberOfTasks which is of type int. It basically fetches the current value of this property and increments it.

However as tasks are executed in the queue, the final value is not coming to be correct because of the threading issue. Sometimes, two tasks tries to update the proeprty at the same time and hence sometime the increment isnt done.

Could anyone please help in getting this done correctly?

Datastore Property Getter Method:

```
private String doGet(String rowId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    Key egsKey = KeyFactory.createKey(DATASTORE_KIND, rowId);

    Entity egsEntity = datastore.get(egsKey);

    // schema changed from String to Text type. Transparently handle that here.
    Object propertyValue = egsEntity.getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY);

    if (propertyValue instanceof String) {
        return (String) propertyValue;
    }

    Text text = (Text) propertyValue;

    return text.getValue();
}
```

Datastore Property SETTER METHOD:

```
private void doPut(String rowId, List<String> list) {
    Entity entity = new Entity(DATASTORE_KIND, rowId);
    entity.setProperty(PROPERTY_KEY, list);

    datastore.put(entity);
}
```

Setter and Getter Methods:

```
public synchronized int getPendingUsersForProcessing() {
    String pendingUsersForProcessingAsString = null;
    try {
        pendingUsersForProcessingAsString = doGet(PENDING_USERS_FOR_PROCESSING);
        return Integer.valueOf(pendingUsersForProcessingAsString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The num of last batches processed in Datastore is not a number: "
                + pendingUsersForProcessingAsString);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        return DEFAULT_PENDING_USERS_FOR_PROCESSING;
    }
}

/** {@inheritDoc } */
@Override
public synchronized void setPendingUsersForProcessing(int pendingUsersForProcessing) {
    doPut(PENDING_USERS_FOR_PROCESSING, String.valueOf(pendingUsersForProcessing));
    LOG.info("Number of Pending Users For Processing is set to : " + pendingUsersForProcessing);
}
```

Code Where I am trying to update the property:

```
int pendingUsers = appProperties.getPendingUsersForProcessing();
int requestUsers = request.getUserKeys().size();
appProperties.setPendingUsersForProcessing(pendingUsers + requestUsers);
```

Comment: Have you tried transactions as per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions , or for better performance counter-sharding as per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly a threading issue as you may have multiple instances of your app performing the tasks, and those instances do not know about each other. So this is a contention situation.

You have several options on how to resolve it.

1. Use [sharding for your counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).
2. Instead of constantly updating the same entity, create a new entity for each completed task, using the time when a task was completed as an id. The advantage of this approach is that it creates an audit trail and you can always get stats like the number of tasks completed today, within the last hour, etc. To count the number of entities you can use a keys-only query, which is almost free and very fast. The disadvantage is a higher cost of writing these entities - this is not a solution if you have a very large number of tasks to complete.
3. Instead of counting tasks, count the results of these tasks. For example, if a task updates a user status, you can count the number of users with "pending" status using a free and fast keys-only query. This is a very good approach if you already have an indexed property that you can use as a flag to count the tasks completed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I am looking at Sharding as an option as you suggested, however it seems a little overkill for one counter, isnt it? Also,how do we know, how many shards are ideal, because even if one count update fails, the counter becomes corrupt and gives wrong value? For the option 2, its costly as you suggested.

Comment: I didnt understand the option 3. I have lots of users to process and I created batches of those users say 50 in a batch, and schedule a tasks of for that batch. Also, I create a task which create the batches of users from the whole users list. When I run the code, the app starts creating tasks of create batches as well as processing those batches, so these tasks run in parallel until the users list are empty and put into batches tasks. So before running the code again, I put a check that the number of users added in batches tasks, must be equal to number of users processed.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to count tasks at all - you can always create a new batch if there are users that have to be processed - there is no need to wait until the previous tasks have been completed. When you add a user to a batch, simply change the status from "pending" to "being processed". Then change it to "processed" (or whatever you call it) when a task is completed. This way you can run a query for "pending" users at any time, and you can see how many users are "being processed" at any time.

Comment: Actually, the users are Not the entities in my tasks. When I run the task that create batches, what it does is, it puts the IDs of the users in query string and adds a task for that particular batch. So what I do is I have created two counters, one of which is called usersAdded which I update when I put a batch for processing and other is usersProcessed which I update when the task in completed for a particular batch. So when these two counters become equal I assume that all the tasks are completed.
Do you suggest making entities for the users at the time of creating batches and adding task?